# How to make picture top of the list view on Android

Tags: android, list, listview, mobile

I want put a picture at the top of the screen and then a description as a text view  under the picture and finally on the bottom a list view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a LinearLayout and add imageView in it. Then add a listView to LinearLayout.

Alternatively, create a RelativeLayout, add imageView in it and add listView by setting attribute `android:layout_below:"@+id/yourImageViewId"`.

Comment: You should mark as answer if it solved your problem or people may not want to answer your questions.